# David Lewis and probability

Tags: philosophy-of-science, epistemology, metaphysics, probability, david-lewis

I have read a general overview on David Lewis in order to have an idea of his philosophical perspective and in particular about humean supervenience. I am wondering how Lewis considers probability in nature (not in logic)? Does he adhere to subjectivism or objectivism? I have read something about dispositions and he seems to rule them out due to the fact that he believes in the supervenient base. Does this mean that he is a subjectivist?

Comment: this question would be nicer to read with some links / definitions :)

Comment: David Lewis' position is stated in his paper "A Subjectivist's Guide to Objective Chance", which can be found in his Philosophical Papers Vol. 2, pp. 83-132, together with a postscript in which he responds to objections. He allows that there are both subjectivist probabilities, which he calls credences or degrees of belief, and objective chances, which are dispositions. He attempts to relate the two through what he calls the Principal Principle.